# (VBA Outlook) Prompt a message box when sending blanket mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

i am wondering if you can all help me, i recently accidentally sent out a blanket email using the To field instead of BCC to about 800 customers.

Is there any way in outlook that it could detect the number of email addresses in the To, CC fields and if more than 5, prompt a message box saying, are you sure?

I suspect VBA

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested this ... this should help you

```
item As Outlook.MailItem

strNames = item.To
For i = 1 To Len(strNames)
    If Mid(strNames, i, 1) = ";" Then j = j + 1
Next i

strNames = item.CC
For i = 1 To Len(strNames)
    If Mid(strNames, i, 1) = ";" Then k = k + 1
Next i

strNames = item.BCC
For i = 1 To Len(strNames)
    If Mid(strNames, i, 1) = ";" Then l = l + 1
Next i
```

j, k, l give the number of recipients in TO, CC, BCC respectively